# Use the result of strlen as length of char*

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, declaration, string-literals

My intention is to create a `char[]` from the length of a `char*` I've already created.

I asked myself why this is not valid:

```
void copyStringsV2() {
    const char* source = "this is my string.";
    const int length = strlen(source);

    const char* dest[length];
}
```

The compiler gives me this hint:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4101   'str_b': unreferenced local variable    CStrings     
xxx\cstrings.cpp    46  
Error   C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant   CStrings     
xxx\cstrings.cpp    161 
Error (active)  E0028   expression must have a constant value   CStrings     
xxx\CStrings.cpp    161
```

May you can help me out here?

Comment: Have a look at [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: What is your actual goal? Because this code is misconceived. Whatever you are really trying to do, there's a better way to do it.

Comment: question suffers from [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/), please focus question on actual problem not on your solution of this problem.

Comment: The compiler's not smart enough to realize that `const char* source = "this is my string.";` won't change at runtime, so `const int length = strlen(source);` won't change at runtime and therefore `length` could be a compile-time constant usable as an array dimension.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks you man, i just had on my mind that strlen is sth becoming true on runtime :)

Comment: @skrrrt thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to declare a *variable-length array*, [which is not a standard feature in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/65863). A fixed-length array must have its length known at compile-time. That is what the compiler error is complaining about.

If you don't know the length until runtime, you will have to allocate the copied string dynamically instead, such as via `new[]`:

```cpp
void copyStringsV2()
{
    const char* source = "this is my string.";
    const int length = strlen(source);
    char* dest = new char[length+1];
    strcpy(dest, source);
    ...
    delete[] dest;
}
```

Or `std::vector`, so you don't need to use `new[]`/`delete[]` directly:

```cpp
#include <vector>

void copyStringsV2()
{
    const char* source = "this is my string.";
    const int length = strlen(source);
    std::vector<char> dest(length+1);
    strcpy(dest.data(), source);
    ...
}
```

But, in this case, it would be better to use `std::string` instead:

```cpp
#include <string>

void copyStringsV2()
{
    const char* source = "this is my string.";
    std::string dest = source;
    ...
}
```

Comment: buuut... this means that
 "const int length = strlen(source);"
is evaluated at runtime.
correct me if im wrong please!

Comment: Yes, `strlen()` is evaluated at runtime only.  If you want a compile-time evaluation, you would have to use something more like this instead: `const char source[] = "this is my string."; const int length = std::size(source)-1;`  Or the `char_traits::length()` solution that @eerorika showed you.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you should use the type `size_t` instead of the type `int` in this declaration

```
const int length = strlen(source);
      ^^^
```

This constant is a constant of the run-time. So you may not use it in the declaration

```
const char* dest[length];
```

because here is declared a variable length array and variable length arrays (`VLA`) is not a standard C++ feature.

Also it is unclear why the type of elements of the array is `const char *` instead `const char`.

And moreover a constant object shall be initialized.

Comment: thank you for sharing, i dont wanna be to curious but why i should use size_t instead of int?
is that something which helps me to survive the first days and why? :D

Comment: @SirRollalot size_t is the return type of the function strlen. In general an object of the type int can be not large enough to accommodate all values of the type size_t.

Answer (score 2):

> My intention is to create a `char[]`
>
> ```
> const char* dest[length];
> ```

That's not an array of char. That's an array of pointers to const char.

Also, if you want the array to be able to fit the original null termiated string, you must include the null terminator in the length of the array so that its size is `length + 1`.

> I asked myself why this is not valid:
>
> The compiler gives me this hint:
>
> ```
> expression did not evaluate to a constant
> ```
>
> May you can help me out here?

The size of an array must be a compile time constant. `length` is not a constant, therefore it cannot be used as length of an array.

Length of a string cannot be calculated at compile time through a pointer to element of the string. However, if you used a reference for example, and if you used a `constexpr` function to get the length, and used a `constexpr` (`const` works too) variable, then you could use it as the size of an array. There is such function in the C++ standard library:

```
auto& source = "this is my string.";
constexpr auto length = std::char_traits<char>::length(source);
char dest[length + 1];
```

Comment: so that means that strlen is used at runtime isnt it?

Comment: @SirRollalot As far as the abstract machine is concerned, yes it is. Although the optimiser is likely to do compile time magic regardless.

Comment: @eeroika aaand "That's not an array of char. That's an array of pointers to const char."
does that mean that i allocate 1/2 for pointers and 1/2 for the chars? -.-

Comment: @SirRollalot I don't understand your question.

Comment: @eeroika does that mean when i create a array of pointers i could save memory when i do it another way?

Answer (score 1):

> why this is not compilable

Because this is C++, and C++ provide a wide variety of tools already<sup>1</sup>. Your best bet will be `std::string`. Strings can be copied and passed around with no additional code to write.

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string source = "this is my string.";
    const std::string dest = source;
    // do something with dest
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> So you don't need [variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), which are not part of C++.

Comment: thanks for sharing, this will be the next chapter in my book.
i just wanna learn als the basic stuff before i become lazy :D

Comment: This is not laziness, this is c++. If you want useless complications try cobol. If you want useful complications, ho boy you'll be happy in the next chapters!

Comment: just wanna be capable of the stuff before i learn dealing with classes that makes my life a programmer easier. coming from java, some years of laziness already inside me :D